# how to fill the cells of a DataGridView directly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to insert data directly in the cells of a datagrid and then send it to the database , but the rows are not being added with data, they remain empty after the insertion, despite the data appears in the cells.value when I run the code line by line using F11. The database is well linked to the datagrid because when I use textboxes to put the data in the datagrid cells, it works, but it doesn´t work when I put data directly in the cells, through the following code:

```
 public void BD_Conexao()
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("driver= {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=xxxx; database=lic; uid=estagio; password=1234; option = 3 ");
            con.Open();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro na ligação à base de dados. \n{0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }

    }
public void Consulta()
    {
        con = new OdbcConnection("driver= {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=xxxx; database=lic; uid=estagio; password=1234; option = 3 ");
        con.Open();

        OdbcCommand Command = con.CreateCommand();
        Command.CommandText = "select lojas.Id, lojas.NIF, lojas.Loja, lojas.Bloqueado, lojas.DataFim, lojas.lastupdate, lojas.Nome";


        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Command.Connection = con;

        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = Command;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        grid_lic.DataSource = dataSet;

        grid_lic.DataMember = dataSet.Tables[0].TableName;
      }

 private void bt_preencher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   BD_Conexao();

   string DataFim = dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   string lastupdate = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Commandtext = "insert into lojas (NIF,Loja,bloqueado, DataFim, lastupdate, Nome) values (@NIF,@Loja,@Bloqueado,@DataFim,@lastupdate,@Nome)";

   OdbcCommand Command = new OdbcCommand(Commandtext, con);

   Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIF", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loja", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bloqueado", checkBox_bloq.Checked);
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFim", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastupdate", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);

   Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Consulta();
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

data gird needs a data source property to fill data, so :

1) Insert all the data in database with your insert statement.

2) Then you need to do something like this to bind your data from database:

```
      string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds);
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: @TiagoDavid : just for second point reading them directly from database. check updated answer

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've put that code in the function Consulta(). But it doesn't work. Data are not being added to the datagrid.